# THREE.BufferGeometry - vertex normals and face normals

Tags: three.js, vertex, normals, buffer-geometry, face

In the documentation for [`THREE.BufferGeometry`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry) is written:

> **normal (itemSize: 3)**
>   Stores the x, y, and z components of the face or vertex normal vector of each vertex in this geometry. Set by .fromGeometry().

When is this variable holding **vertex** normals and when **face** normals?

Is it as simple as if a `THREE.MeshMaterial` is used the normals are interpreted as face normals and when a `THREE.LineMaterial` is used the normals are used as vertex normals? Or is it more complicated then that.

I also understood that `THREE.FlatShading` can be used for rendering a mesh with flat shading (face normals point straight outward).

```
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1000, 1000, 1000 );

material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ 
    color: 0xff0000, 
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
});

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

I would say normals are not necessary any more. Why are my buffer geometries made from for example a `THREE.BoxGeometry` still holding a normal attribute in such case? Is this information still used for rendering or would removing them from the buffer geometry be a possible optimization?

Comment: buffer geometry does not have "face normals" just vertex normals and normal for point on a triangle face is interpolated by gpu from its vertices... When you convert the geometry from Box geometry normals persist because it does not know that you dont want them, you can remove them afterwards or create your own BoxGeometry if your shader does not use them(try and watch console for warnings or read the shader code), removing them automatically would be problematic as you can use the geometry in another object with other material etc

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik Can you post that as an answer? Then I can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferGeometry` normals are vector normals and shader interpolates normal value for each fragment from vertices belonging to that face (in most cases triangle)

when you convert `THREE.BoxGeometry` which has normals computed by default, they stay set up even in the `BufferGeometry` conversion output, as geometry does not have any way to "know" whether you need normals or any of the attributes (material program decides what attributes are used)

you can remove the normals with `geometry.removeAttribute("normal")`